# Copied Ubuntu 18 to new partition, but it does not start

Tags: btrfs, migration

As written in tens of tutorials, I have created new partition (btrfs), copied over all files from original parition (ext4), using cp, rsync.. Tried various methods, copied filesystem seems to be OK. Then I edited new fstab file, replaced with UUID of new partition and changed ext4 to btrfs. I also created new entry in GRUB from the original (I booted old system and ran Grub-Customizer), where I replaced all original UUID with UUID of new partition. I have boot partition sda1, original partition (ext4) is sdb5 and new partition (btrfs) is sdb6. Other people write this worked for them, but new Ubuntu failed to start, with many error messages "[FAILED] Failed to start... and eventually stops at "A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up. And at that point it gets stuck. Any advise or solution please?

Comment: I think it is not possible to restore to other file system on file level. It seems to me that there are too many references to ext4 FS in various config files that the same system configuration does not run on btrfs. Changing Grub and FSTAB is not enough. I wanted to do snapshots because of VmWare open machines. In the end, I stayed with ext4 and I do vmware snapshot of open machine via command  line. That way I obtain vmware vmdk and vmem files that are not written to and can be backed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Creating a startup disk using [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)

Or:

- Create an ubuntu startup disk and reinstall grub2 using [these instructions](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: Thank you but I think this is not necessary. The system boots. With errors for about 10 seconds then it gets stuck. I would say grub does its job.